# Steaming fragmented Webm over websocket to MediaSouce

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webm, media-source

I am trying to do the following:

On the server I encode h264 packets into Webm (MKV) container structure, so that each cluster gets a single frame packet.Only the first data chunk is different as it contains something called Initialization Segment.[Here it is explained quite well](https://axel.isouard.fr/blog/2016/05/24/streaming-webm-video-over-html5-with-media-source).
Then I stream those clusters one by one in a binary stream via WebSocket to a broweser, which is Chrome.
It probably sounds weird that I use h264 codec and not VP8 or VP9, which are native codec for Webm Video Format. But it appears that html [video tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) has no problem to play this sort of video container. If I just write the whole stream to a file and pass it to video.src, it is played fine. But I want to stream it in real-time.That's why I am breaking the video into chunks and sending them over websocket. 
On the client, I am using [MediaSource API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). I have little experience in Web technologies, but I found that's probably the only way to go in my case.

And it doesn't work.I am getting no errors, the streams runs ok, and the video object emits no warning or errors (checking via developer console).
The client side code looks like this:

```
<script>

 $(document).ready(function () {
  var sourceBuffer;
  var player = document.getElementById("video1");
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource();

  player.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
  //array with incoming segments:
  var mediaSegments = [];
  var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/echo"); 
  ws.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

  player.addEventListener("error", function (err) {
    $("#id1").append("video error "+ err.error + "\n");
  }, false);

  player.addEventListener("playing", function () {
    $("#id1").append("playing\n");
  }, false);
  player.addEventListener("progress",onProgress);

  ws.onopen = function () {
    $("#id1").append("Socket opened\n");
  };

  function sourceOpen()
  {
     sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001E"');
  }

  function onUpdateEnd()
  {
    if (!mediaSegments.length)
    {
       return;
    }
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(mediaSegments.shift());
  }

  var initSegment = true;
  ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
    if (evt.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      var buffer = evt.data;
     //the first segment is always 'initSegment'
     //it must be appended to the buffer first
     if(initSegment == true)
     {
         sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
         sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', onUpdateEnd);
         initSegment = false;
     }
     else
     {  
        mediaSegments.push(buffer);
     }
    }
   };
 });
```

I also tried different profile codes for MIME type,even though I know that my codec is "high profile.I tried the following profiles:

**avc1.42E01E baseline**

**avc1.58A01E extended profile**

**avc1.4D401E main profile**

**avc1.64001E high profile**

In some examples I found from 2-3 years ago, I have seen developers using type= "video/x-matroska", but probably alot changed since then,because now even video.src doesn't handle this sort of MIME.

Additionally, in order to make sure the chunks I am sending through the stream are not corrupted, I opened a local streaming session in VLC player and it played it progressively with no issues.
The only thing I suspect that the MediaCodec doesn't know how to handle this sort of hybrid container.And I wonder then why video object plays such a video ok.Am I missing something in my client side code? Or MediacCodec API indeed doesn't support this type of media?

PS: For those curious why I am using MKV container and not MPEG DASH, for example. The answer is - container simplicity, data writing speed and size. [EBML](https://github.com/Matroska-Org/ebml-specification) structures are very compact and easy to write in real time.

Comment: I haven't ran your code... but you're sending in the wrong content type when you instantiate your source buffer.  It's `video/webm`... but it's not really WebM, because you're not using the right codecs.  Switch to VP8 video, Opus audio, and get it working with WebM first.

Comment: Then why video src plays this video with no problems?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459893/html5-video-stream-from-websocket-via-mediasource-and-mediasourcebuffer