# HTML5 Video stream from websocket via MediaSource and MediaSourceBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, http-live-streaming, media-source

I'm trying to play video from websocket

```
<video id="output" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>

<script>
    function sockets(buffer) {
        const socket = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:5002/ws')

        socket.onmessage = async function (event) {
            // event.data is a blob
            buffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(event.data))
        }
    }

    let ms = new MediaSource()
    let output = document.getElementById('output')
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms)
    ms.onsourceopen = () => {
        let buffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('video/webm; codecs="vorbis,vp8"')
        sockets(buffer)
    }
</script>
```

I receive MediaRecorder chunks here as Blobs and try to sequentially play them using MediaSource API. No errors and nothing happens. Is there something fundamentally wrong here?

I tried:

- To use different codecs
- Played with media source modes e.g sequence/segments
- I was also trying different ways where you don't use MediaSource API but faced other challenges and MediaSource seems to be the best approach in my case.

UPDATE: this is how the video is produced:

```
let options = { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8' }
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options)
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = event => {
    if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        send(event.data)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the video produced. what codec/container? What'd does chrome media internals say?

Comment: @szatmary I've updated the post. Please take a look

Comment: @Andrei Go to `chrome://media-internals` as suggested by szatmary to get additional information.  Also, your source only has a video stream, but you're specifying video and audio codecs on the receiving end.  You shouldn't also assume the codec you get back from MediaRecorder will be the one you requested.  Use the resulting `mimeType` on the blob.

Answer (score -1):

The fundamental problem here is you cannot stream those data coming out of `MediaRecorder` and expect the other end to play it; it is not a complete video. It will only work if the receiving end is able to receive the *initialization bytes*--which I doubt that will work in a real-world scenario.

What you can do is to create an interval that will start/stop the `MediaRecorder` for example every 1 second to make 1 second video chunks that you can transmit over the wire (best I know and tested is websockets)

I strongly suggest not to use `MediaRecorder` is you are doing real-time video streaming which was not indicated in your post, but if yes, it would be better that you create a canvas to copy the stream and do some `requestAnimationFrame` stuff that can capture your video stream into a something you can transmit.

Take a look at this demo for reference: https://github.com/cyberquarks/quarkus-websockets-streamer/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/index.html

`MediaRecorder` in my experience response is delayed that would generally add quite a delay in the video, not to mention the delay that the socket would also introduce.

Generally, other developers would suggest that you just take the WebRTC route, however based on my experience also WebRTC is not generally faster.

Comment: You *can* stream data out of MediaRecorder and play it back later.  Especially with WebM, this is trivial.  The initialization data is everything up to the first Cluster.  Your interval example has no guarantee of working... starting/stoppping the MediaRecorder is asynchronous and doesn't necessarily fall at any particular time.  It may work for you today in some places, but isn't guaranteed to work.  MediaRecorder is fine for real-time streaming.  Low latency is not everyone's requirement.  Often times, it's preferable to *not* drop frames and audio.

Comment: @Brad would you be able to elaborate on it in the answer? You seem to know what you're talking about :). Thank you.

Comment: @Andrei you can push yourself to use MediaStream to stream over the wire that's possible (never said it is not possible) the problem I am pointing out is you won't achieve real-time, you can search all over Stackoverflow and no one suggest using it for real-time. If you don't need real-time then MediaRecorded is the easiest way to go.

Comment: @Brad the start/stop worked for my simple demo but again never used that because it is slow, I even asked Mozilla developers and they said to just use the canvas for real-time. However you mention MediaRecorder is okay for real-time streaming, that's new and if fact if it is then it's great, do you have sample or demo that can showcase this? Since last time I remember I was using MediaRecorder for our prototype real-time streaming and the reason I switched to canvas is the video that MediaRecorder emits is already delayed how much more if we introduce network delay.

Comment: @quarks What is your latency requirement?  With MediaRecorder, don't go below a second on the encoding.  If you want low latency, you should use WebRTC.  Not everyone requires the lowest of low latency.  If you don't, it's better to favor quality, which you can do with MediaRecorder.

Comment: Here's an old code sample:  https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example

Comment: @Brad I was looking at `ws.send(e.data);` and saw that the client is sending out the data directly to the server, I can see now what you mean, yes I think using FFMPEG on the server will solve any streaming problem as it can process the incoming stream and fan out, but I haven't seen up to now in my research that was able to do it in pure Javascript. Like `MediaRecorder --> websocket --> MediaSource`  without ffmpeg or something in between other then a socket.

Comment: You can do it without FFmpeg by streaming directly into a `<video>` element.  No need for MediaSource Extensions.  So, MediaRecorder -> Web Socket -> Passive Server -> HTTP -> Video Element.  If you do want to drop into a live stream, you just need the data of the WebM up to the first Cluster, and then start on any Cluster that begins with a keyframe.  I'm not at a computer right now, but there's another Stack Overflow answer where I have the details... I'll see if I can find it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm having similar problem,i am able to stream live video via mediarecorder and websockets but if some one peeps into middle of media stream ,he wont be able to see the video.I know that some init segments are required. How to generate that ?

Comment: actaully, canvas is a bad solution becauseof its poor efficiency,and it wastes a lot of system resources.